# Letting UL to expand horizontally only

Tags: html, css

I need to dynamically add LI elements to the UL element which are of "n" length. The HTML I have right now is...

```
<div class="center">
    <ul id="tabList" class="parent">
        <!-- I am adding LI using jQuery here. -->
        <br class="clearfix" />
    </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS applied here is...

```
.center
{
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 15%;
    width: 70%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.center ul.parent
{
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;   
}

.center ul.parent li
{
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.center ul.parent li .tab
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 49px;    
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    color: #A9D0F5;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

I must set **.parent** width according to its children width in order not to let UL expand vertically here. Is there a way I can use to fix the width setting? I don't like setting width according to children accumulated width.

Comment: Can you put a image to see what is you want?

Comment: if you would be at docs.google.com with new spreadsheet opened, you would notice sheet tabs at the bottom. I want to create similar thing.

Comment: What would you like to have happen when the jQuery added `li`s are wider than 70% of the screen?

Comment: I would just like the UL not to wrap those LI and the LI should be overflowing the UL but still not being shown on the body without using overflow: hidden.

Comment: Because the LI has child UL which is shown when the mouse is over LI and because the .center has overflow: hidden, the nested UL never shows.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Galled/KQqYm/)?

I put a big witdh in order to avoid that the new `LI`s going down.

```
.center ul.parent
{
    width: 1000%;
}
```

But I think that your problem are here:

```
.center
{
    width: 70%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Will come a time where the `.center` will not allow to show new `LI`s.

I recommend to you, because you will add `LI` tags with jQuery, detect the first width of the `.center ul.parent` and increment it programmatically in each new `LI` addition.

From what you tell me in the comments I make another demo to see if it help you --> http://jsfiddle.net/Galled/KQqYm/4/

Comment: I am right now doing the same. But I thought if there was a CSS way to do that, it would be wonderful.

Comment: Is there another way to do that assuming the center must have width 70% but the overflow: hidden would be removed? I mean any other way by jQuery or CSS?

Comment: @UmairAshraf Why you would remove `overflow:hidden` you need to see all the tabs? Maybe you could use `overflow:auto`

Comment: I don't need to see all tabs but those which can be visible in available space. Rest tabs would be shown upon user clicking next/prev button. The overflow:auto would bring horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: So I think with only `overflow:hidden` is enough, with the code of clicking next/prev you can play with `.center ul.parent { margin-left:-any_valuepx } ` or `.center ul.parent { margin-right:-any_valuepx } `

Comment: You could try something like [this](http://www.designmadeingermany.de/slideshow/)

Comment: I have already done that using parent's left position and everything is working fine except the nested UL thing. The LI has nested UL which is a dropdown menu shown on LI:hover. Because this nested UL is inside the .center element and .center has overflow:hidden, the nested UL is going behind the show thing. In simple words, how to bring nested UL to front keeping overflow:hidden?

Comment: I see you setting 500% of width. but what if the content is even outside 500%?

Comment: depends of the viewport of your client. To mantain this aspect you will do the equivalence --> `.center {width: 100% * X;}` => `.center {width: margin:0 15% / X;}` so, if you have `.center {width: 500% /* 100%*5 */;}` you need `.center {width: margin:0 3% /* 15% / 5 */;}`, if you have `.center {width: 700% /* 100%*7 */;}` you need `.center {width: margin:0 2.15% /* 15% / 7 */;}` and so on.

Comment: Mmmm not necessarily if you know that your client has a specific limit (and your tabs too) you would make a big % (500 is big, is 1024*5 at least) but, if not, you need to use js.